# How to edit wp-signup.php content using plugin

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I need your help as I got some issue with `wp-signup.php` page which I try to resolve but I am not able to do it.

Issue is as follows,

1. I want to replace the text 'Get your own %s account in seconds'
   with 'Fields with an asterisk will be shown on your website for the 
   world to see'.
   I know that i can do it by going to the `wp-signup.php` page and hardcode the text in `signup_user()` but i want it to be handle with the help of a plugin so that even if wordpress upgrade then this will not affect the text.
2. I want to remove radio button with label (Just a username, please.) from the `signup_user()`

Any help will be appriciated, I am waiting for you reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try these hooks:

```
// 
// remove label label[for=signupuser] and #signupuser on wp-signup.php with CSS
// 
add_action('signup_header','my_signup');
function my_signup() {
    echo "<style>label[for=signupuser],#signupuser{display:none !important;}</style>";
}

//
// edit text displayed on wp-signup.php 
//
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_change_text', 20 ,3);
function my_change_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( $domain =="your_site_name") { // EDIT
        if( trim($translated_text)=="Get your own %s account in seconds"){
                $translated_text="Fields with an asterisk will be shown on your website for the world to see";
        }
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

where you will have to edit the value **$domain =="your_site_name"**.

This will give you the following result (see the attached image):

[image: wp-signup modifications via hooks]

Comment: Thanksssssssssssss a ton, you have saved my lot's of time, it's work for me.